# Oracle Apex Item ID (XXX) is not an item defined on the current page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Clicking on a Save button gives error - Item ID (123) is not an item defined on the current page. Contact your application administrator.
I have tried running the below query to find out the item, however, this query gives no data found.
select * from apex_application_page_items where item_id = '123';

Can someone please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Is that the exact error message? If not, could you please provide the exact message?

Comment: Nevermind, I just reproduced it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a specific error message. It means that the item (123) does exist in the app, but shouln't have been submitted with the page. It could be an application-level item rather than a page item. Try running this JavaScript code in the console to see if you can find the element (just replace 123 with the correct item name):

```
$('#123,[name="123"]').length
```

Comment: Thank you for the turnaround. I tried running this on console and it gave me 0(Zero).

Comment: Priya, if this is still an issue, feel free to contact me (see links in my profile).

Comment: Sure,Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an item manually and missed to check all its properties, then it might have been created with a source set to a **database column** (whose name is equal to page item name). That's usually the case when you create a display item; if so, just set its source to null.

Alternatively, enable **debug** mode, run the page and then view debug results. In there, you'll see what's going on during page submit and - hopefully - fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have checked all the items and all of their source have been set to NULL. I also tried. debug mode and this is what I have got :
Logging exception in final_exception_handler:
Sqlerrm: ORA-20987: APEX - Item ID (35485) is not an item defined on the current page. - Contact your application administrator.
Details about this incident are available via debug id "2005".
Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 734
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1015
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW", line 6037

Comment: Did you click on that debug number (2005) in debug console, which leads you to more detailed info?

Comment: Yes, this msg I have got after clicking debug number(2005) only :

Comment: Also, Item id is changing every day. It is showing Item ID (34430) today.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if im late , but this could be worthy for the apex beginners.

it's simple. *"just delete the item and create it again"* works for me